# Add-in/App - avoid consent dialog when adding app to a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-addin, azure

Is there a way to "trust" an SharePoint Add-in/App after it has been uploaded to the app catalog? Or eventually before/when it is added.

[image]

**The App is an SharePoint Add-in (.app file) and is hosted on Azure as a Web App. The installation prosess is: a Site Design triggers a Flow that activates a Function that executes a PowerShell script with Apply-PnPTemplate.**

On Azure there is no connection to SharePoint so I guess this stops the installation.

When the App is added manually to a site there is a consent dialog popping up, and is there a way to avoid this? (with powershell or in the SharePoint admin center, or maybe something else)

***Appreciate any thoughts and answers***

Answer (score 0):

You should try [ALM API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/alm-api-for-spfx-add-ins):

> ALM APIs provide simple APIs to manage deployment of your SharePoint Framework solutions and add-ins across your tenant.

With [PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) you can add your app:

```
Add-PnPApp -Path ./myapp.sppkg -Scope Tenant
```

Deploy it:

```
Publish-PnPApp -Identity <app id> -SkipFeatureDeployment -Scope Tenant
```

And install at any particular site:

```
Install-PnPApp -Identity <app id> -Scope Tenant
```

[Office 365 CLI](https://pnp.github.io/office365-cli/cmd/spo/app/app-add/) also has corresponding APIs.

Comment: I tried adding the App to the app catalog again with PowerShell and then Publish-PnPApp with correct ID -Scope Tenant and also -SkipFeatureDeployment parameters. But it fails: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Seems to be a known issue:
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1296

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if setting the Tenant scope permission level to FullControl could fix the issue?

[image]